# Cloudformation Hide parameters in Wizard

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wish to keep instance type / VPC etc private for users using my cloudformation script. Does anyone know of a way to hide these parameters during the stack creation wizard?

I know echo keeps the values private, but is there a way for it all to not be displayed on screen.

Ideally it would ask for Stack name and the rest of the page would be blank.

Comment: What is about using `Default` together with `AllowedValues` options? Cause parameters are never private as soon as they are part of a plain-text CloudFormation template.

Comment: I'm using default so its a set value. I just don't want those parameter titles / values appearing in the create stack wizard. Is it possible?

Comment: I still want them to run during the stack creation, but just not displayed for the user in the wizard

Comment: @PropK why not just set the attributes on your resources directly then?

Comment: Set the attributes in resources instead of the parameters, I will try it

Comment: if the attribute has been used in lot of places in the CloudFormation template, I just don't want to hardcode the value in all those places. I want to keep a hidden parameter with default value, so that later on, when I need to change the value, I need to change in one place only.

Answer (score 2):

For sensitive parameter values (such as passwords), set the NoEcho property to true. That way, whenever anyone describes your stack, the parameter value is shown as asterisks (*****).

Although in your case, this cannot prevent the user of checking the instance type inside their respective tabs. Probably is a better idea to restrict the access of users to confidential information using IAM policies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud formation macro do such thing, Macro will help you to transform your template at runtime.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Public-and-Private-Subnet-per-AZ